# Analizing the stability of the equilibrium points of the system $\ddot{x}=(x-a)(x^2-a)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems

$\require{amsmath}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Det}{Det}$

> Investigate the stability of the equilibrium points of the system $\ddot{x}=(x-a)(x^2-a)$ for all real values of the parameter $a$. (Hints: It might help to
>   graph the right-hand side. An alternative is to rewrite the equation as $\ddot{x}=−V′(x)$ for a suitable potential energy function $V$ and then use your intuition about particles
>   moving in potentials.)

I am not really sure on how to approach the problem with the given hints, since it would require plotting the graph for different critical values for $a$, which I am not really sure how to find. Thus, I am wondering if the following is correct.

The system $\ddot{x}=(x-a)(x^2-a)$ can be re-written as
$$\begin{cases}
\dot{x}=y\\
\dot{y}=(x-a)(x^2-a)
\end{cases}$$
with fixed points $P_1(a,0),\,P_2(\sqrt{a},0)$ and $P_3(\sqrt{a},0)$.

The Jacobian is 
$$J(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1\\
3x^2-2ax-a &0
\end{bmatrix}$$
and thus
$$J(a,0)=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1\\
a^2-a &0
\end{bmatrix};\quad J(\sqrt{a},0)=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1\\
2a-2a^{3/2} &0
\end{bmatrix}; \quad J(-\sqrt{a},0)=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1\\
2a+2a^{3/2} &0
\end{bmatrix}.$$
It can be noticed that the $\Tr\left[J(x,y)\right]=0$ and that 
$$\begin{aligned}
&1.\,\Det\left[J(a,0)\right]=a(1-a)\implies \text{Saddle for }a<0 \wedge a>1, \text{Center for }0<a<1.\\
&2.\,\Det\left[J(\sqrt{a},0)\right]=2a(\sqrt{a}-1)\implies \text{Saddle for }0<a<1, \text{Center for }a>1.\\
&3.\,\Det\left[J(-\sqrt{a},0)\right]=-2a(\sqrt{a}+1)\implies \text{Saddle for }a>0.
\end{aligned}$$

If $a=0$ the system reduces to $\ddot{x}=x^3$ where the only fixed point is at $(0,0)$ and thus it is unstable. On the other hand, if $a=1$ then the system reduces to $\ddot{x}=x^3-x^2-x+1$ with fixed points at $(1,0),(-1,0)$, both being unstable.

Is my work correct?

Comment: Isn't this question better suited for Physics SE?

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost this is part of dynamical systems, so no. I could certainly ask there too, but there is no point really

Comment: That's funny what you did, It was a genuine question. No need to get defensive. Cheers!

Comment: I haven't checked all your algebra carefully but it looks like you've go the right idea!

Comment: Graphically, for $a=0.5$, I'm seeing a saddle at $-\sqrt{a}$ instead of a center. May want to double check that one.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 yes you're right the determinant is always negative. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost everything looks right.

For $a > 0$, $-2a < 0$ and $\sqrt{a}+1 > 0$, so $\Det[J(-\sqrt{a},0)] < 0$. This equilibrium should be a saddle then for positive $a$.

Also, when analyzing the stability of a system with a parameter, it helps to draw the bifurcation diagram, i.e. the graph of the fixed points with respect to the parameter. The fixed point equations $x = a, x = \sqrt{a}, x = -\sqrt{a}$ can be graphed on the $ax$-plane. Intersections of these curves are the bifurcations, which are the only places where the behavior can change.

[image: bifurcation diagram]

This is the bifurcation diagram for your system. The lower black curve is the $x=-\sqrt{a}$ equilibrium, which doesn't have any intersections for $a>0$, so there will be no change in behavior.

---

Edit:

This isn't specifically asked about in the question but it is an important feature of this equation. For $a>0, a\neq 1$, there are centers at one fixed point and saddles at another nearby fixed point. When this happens, a periodic orbit will collide  with the saddle point, creating a closed path from a fixed point back around to itself. This is called a homoclinic orbit, and usually has a "teardrop" shape, as seen below for $a = \frac{1}{2}$.

[image: homoclinic orbit]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what software did you use to sketch the phase plane?

Comment: pplane, which can be found here as a java application: https://math.rice.edu/~dfield/dfpp.html I strongly recommend it to any student in dynamics. It's limited to plane dynamics (obviously) but can be extremely helpful in learning and verifying results.

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestion!